# Swift 4 custom argument labels - required?

Tags: swift, function, arguments

```
func greet (person person: String, on day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) on \(day)"
}
```

can be executed as

> greet ("John", "23")

Swift 4 - custom argument labels behave as no argument label - **"_"**.

How to make custom labels mandatory for execution?

> greet (person: "John", on: "23")

Thanks.

Edit - question is incorrect, as custom labels are mandatory

Comment: Executing your code in a playground yields the expected error _"Missing argument labels 'person:on:' in call"_. Are you sure you don't have an overloaded version without argument labels implemented by accident?

Comment: The `func greet(person person: String, on day: String) -> String { ... }` cannot be executed as `greet("John", "23")`. By the way, the extra `person` is redundant. It would be `func greet(person: String, on day: String) -> String { ... }`.

Comment: excuting this func as greet("John", "23") will get compilation error "Missing argument labels 'person:on:' in call"

Comment: Thanks, seems I've provided many function definitions in Swift's command line and compiler mixed these definitions, so it was possible for me to execute function as greet ("John", "23"). Your answer is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Swift` each function parameter can have both **`argument label`** and a **`parameter name`**.

1. **`argument label`**: used in function call
2. **`parameter name`**: used inside the function definition

By default, `parameters` use their `parameter name` as their `argument label`.

These are the possible function declarations that can be used in swift:

**Case 1:**  `parameter name` is same as the `argument label`

```
func greet (person: String, day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) on \(day)"
}
```

*Function Call*: `greet(person: "John", day: "23")`

**Case 2:**  different `parameter name` and `argument label`

```
func greet (person person: String, on day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) on \(day)"
}
```

*Function Call*: `greet(person: "John", on: "23")`

**Case 3:** using `_` as `argument label`

```
func greet (_ person: String, _ day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) on \(day)"
}
```

*Function Call*: `greet("John", "23")`

For more on how function parameters work, you can refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Thanks, seems I have provided many function definitions in Swift's command line and compiler mixed these definitions, so it was possible for me to execute function as greet ("John", "23"). Your answer is perfect, thanks.

Comment: Sure. Happy coding 