# Are Swift 4 custom argument labels ALWAYS required or just for disambiguation of functions?

Tags: swift, function, arguments, label

This question is similar to
[Swift 4 custom argument labels - required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349247/swift-4-custom-argument-labels-required)
but more specific. I came across that question when researching a problem caused by changing from a var (requiring no parameter) to a func (requiring a parameter) but missed changing all references. I have created a playground that contradicts the claim made in a subsequent edit to that question: "question is incorrect, as custom labels are mandatory"
My question is: how to correctly express what I observed, as demonstrated below:

```
class SomeTest {
    static func someParam(p1: String?) -> String? {
        return "hello \(p1 ?? "nothing")"
    }

    // Uncommenting the following causes error at let funny
    //    static func someParam(p2: String?) -> String? {
    //        return "hello \(p2 ?? "nothing")"
    //    }

    static func doIt() {
        let funny = someParam // ignoring the argument label is ok if there is no ambiguity

        funny("thing") // and can be used without

        someParam(p1: "thing2") // must have argument label
    }
}

SomeTest.doIt()
```

Comment: You can use a default value, `someParam(p1: String? = nil)`, which will allow you to call the function without parameters (and the value will be defaulted to `nil`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have both `someParam` functions (each with a differently named parameter), then the line:

```
let funny = someParam
```

no longer works since it isn't known which of the two `someParam` functions you are referring to. This is solved by providing an unambiguous name:

```
let funny = someParam(p1:) // or someParam(p2:)
```

Note that `funny` has a type of `(String?) -> String?`. Both `someParam` functions have that same type. This is why you need to provide more detail to disambiguate the two. The parameter names don't change the function type.

When directly calling a function you must provide the full function name which includes any named parameter labels.

But when you create a closure variable and assign it the value of a function, you don't need to provide more than the base name of the function if that name is unambiguous in the given context.